# Can you manually add to an iPhone/iPad Navigation Bar a back button item?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibarbuttonitem

I have a reference to a "UIBarButtonItem", is there a way I can add a custom "Back Navigation Button" to that item when it is not part of a Navigation based view?

I can add a left button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"Custom Back" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
action:@selector(backAction:)];

menuItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton; //This doesn't seem to work.

menuItem.popOverNavigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton; //This shows a normal button
```

So how could I make the leftmost button look like a back navigation button?

UPDATE: This other question answered the root of my problem that was leading me to try and do this non-standard UI setup:
[iPad: Merge concept of SplitViewController and NavigationController in RootView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662833/ipad-merge-concept-of-splitviewcontroller-and-navigationcontroller-in-rootview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct way to set the back button is to set it for the view controller that you would be going back to. For example:

```
RootViewController > DetailViewController
```

If you want the back button to say "Custom Back" whilst you're on DetailViewController, you have to actually set RootViewController's back button to "Custom Back".

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't think that's right. The closest thing to this is setting the `title` property of the `RootViewController` to be the text that appears on the back button of `DetailViewController`.  
Edit: Seems to be right. Have a look: http://www.retainrelease.com/blog/?p=11

Comment: My question is if you could do this to a NavBarItem without using the NavBarController.  (This comes up in the SplitViewController example code.)

Comment: Not without a nav controller, but you don't have to always have a nav bar with a nav controller, so why not have a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Having just struggled with this: I think the answer is “no.” You'll need a controller hierarchy.