# iPad: Merge concept of SplitViewController and NavigationController in RootView?

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm having trouble merging the two concepts of using a SplitViewController in my main view and having the "RootView" controller that controls the left panes popup/sidebar table view.

I want to have the left "RootView" act as a navigation menu, but how do I do this when the RootView is tied through MainWindow.xib into the left pane of the SplitView?

Basically, I want the left navigation to work just like the built-in email applications folder drilldown navigation.  Is there an example iPad project out there that uses both SplitView and a NavigationView for the left/Root pane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you create a SplitView project, open up the RootViewController.m file and look at the -tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  You'll see that the item that you clicked is then set as a property of the DetailViewController.

The design you're looking for would require that you push another view controller onto the navigation stack.  So if you imagine the e-mail application, when a user picks a folder, the detailView is not updated, but the next level of the Inbox is pushed onto the stack.  When a user selects a message from the inbox, the detail view is updated with the message contents, and the RootViewController just stays where it's at.

in the -tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath method, declare your new view controller

```
NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
//This assumes you have another table view controller called NextViewController
//We assign it to the instance variable "nextView"

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
//tells the navigation controller to "slide" the "nextView" instance on top
//if animated:NO it wouldn't slide, it would just "update"

[nextView release];
//release the viewController, it's now retained automatically by the NavigationController
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: very nice help. But just one problem. Justin can u please help? Actually when i go to next View Controller there is another list in it But Clicking on that doe snot updates my Detail View Controller. DetailView only updates when i update it from RootViewController?? Y is that ? what m i missing ??

Comment: You have to update the code in the -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: inside the .m file you're referring to as "next View Controller".  Each individual view controller will most likely have its own .h and .m files, and the code inside controls what happens in the respective view controllers